# CheckListBox - como passar um checklisbox para um função no Delphi

Tags: delphi

Preciso criar um função onde eu passo para a função um CheckListBox e esta função irá armazenar em uma variável os valores do checklistbox.

```
function PegaDescricao(checklistbox .......... ) : String;                                                                          
var i, cont, descricao : Integer;  
begin
  cont := 0;                                   
  for i:=0 to checkListBox.Items.Count-1 do                 
  begin
    if cont = 0 then
    begin  
      cont := contad +1;                                                                                                      
      descricao:=copy(checkListBox.Items.Strings[i],1,Length(checkListBox.Items.Strings[i])-4);                            
    end
    else
      descricao:=descricao+', '+copy(checkListBox.Items.Strings[i],1,Length(checkListBox.Items.Strings[i])-4);  
  end;  
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Como qualquer parâmetro delphi, você precisa declarar o seu tipo. Todos os componentes delphi são objetos, logo basta passar o nome da classe referente ao objeto junto com o parâmetro.

```
function PegaDescricao(checklistbox: TCheckListBox): String;
```

Comment: Com esta dica o problema foi resolvida a questão, apenas corrigindo no lugar do tipo do parâmetro TCkeckListBox tive de utilizar o tipo TfrxCheckListBoxControl. Ficando assim o cabeçalho da função:

function PegaDescricao(checklistbox: TfrxCheckListBoxControl) : String;